# bundle install not working on rails fork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundler

If I checkout or fork [the rails project on github](https://github.com/rails/rails), I get an error when running `bundle install` that sprockets-rails can't be found. How do I get these gems installed?

```
new-host-4:rails scott$ bundle install
Updating git://github.com/rails/arel.git
Updating git://github.com/brynary/rack-test.git
Updating git://github.com/rails/jquery-rails.git
Updating git://github.com/rails/coffee-rails.git
Updating git://github.com/rails/journey.git
Updating git://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders.git
Updating git://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails.git
Updating git://github.com/fxn/sdoc.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Error Bundler::HTTPError during request to dependency API
Fetching full source index from https://rubygems.org/
Could not find gem 'sprockets-rails (~> 2.0) ruby', which is required by gem 'rails (>= 0) ruby', in any of the sources.
```

Comment: Are you trying to install Rails 4.0, or the latest Rails stable?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott - Just doing a checkout of https://github.com/rails/rails.git I guess would be rails 4.0? I could try a stable branch as well. How would I get the latest working though?

Comment: Yes, that is Rails 4.0 and hasn't been released yet... Could you describe what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: There are a couple bugs I'd like to see if I can fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you want to go this route then: https://github.com/rails/rails-dev-box ... the rails repo can't be installed with bundler during active development.

Comment: I'd like to use my tools for debugging and playing around in the code. I guess I'll try the latest stable branch instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your gem file write

```
gem "sprockets-rails", "1.0.0"
```

then, bundle install

Comment: It's not my gem file, it's the rails project's gem file. I should still change that?

Answer (score 0):

http://status.rubygems.org

Rubygems is having growing pains, and issues.  and at the moment the dependency API is down.  So this is a failure of it trying to resolve the dependency via rubygems.  AS for solving it, you can manually install all the requirements on your machine and then bundle should use the local copies.